# What is the alternative for DECLARE and SET in MS SQL for PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, psql

I can write the below in MS SQL, however, need to write this in PostgreSQL

`DECLARE @countryname nvarchar(max) = 'China';`

So that I can use this in;

`Select * from country_table where country=@countryname;`

Comment: You can use variables with `psql` and in procedural language code. You cannot use variables in SQL.

Comment: Thank you, I want to write it in plgsql itself, researched on the web but couldn't understand the solution, can you help me with the syntax or some example? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html) you see how to declare a variable, and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) you see how to assign to it.